# Form group validation

Tags: angular

i want to show message on submit as well , so please correct me how to validate on submit .
**here my html**

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="code" required>
 <label [hidden]="ascForm.controls.code.valid || (ascForm.controls.code.pristine && ascForm.submitted)" class="errorMsg">Cannot save. You must specify a code.</label>
```

this validation condition is working fine if i use template driven approach,
but now i am using Model driven so please correct me **submit** condition.

Answer (score 1):

Common approach is to ***disable*** the submit button, until the form is completely valid.

But if you want to show messages only when the user actually submits the form, lets create in your `FormComponent` boolean property indicating the user tried to post the form. Like:

```
submitAttempt: boolean = false;
```

and on submitting the form, in your component you set it to `true`:

```
submitForm() {
    this.submitAttempt = true;
    ...
  }
```

You can then filter your message just `submitAttempt == true`. Like:

```
<span *ngIf="!code.valid && submitAttempt">Required</span>
```

For deep explanation, see this post: [Angular 2 forms validation](https://auth0.com/blog/angular2-series-forms-and-custom-validation/), (*search the page for 'submitAttempt' to quickly find the referenced part*)

PS: please don't use `label` tag for showing validation errors. It should be used really just for labeling the form inputs.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , its a good alternate for this situation.